Using a static AsyncLocal for an "AsyncFlowId"
We're trying to use a basic AsyncLocal to store an "AsyncFlowId" for simple request tracking. I know, I know- static classes bad, dependency injection good. Regardless, this is the way we're looking to do it. What I'm not clear on is if this is thread-safe to do without taking a lock or not. The AsyncLocal magic makes it harder to reason about.
We have code like this:
public static class RuntimeContext 
{
     private static AsyncLocal<Guid> _asyncFlowId = new AsyncLocal<Guid>();
     public static Guid AsyncFlowId => _asyncFlowId ??= Guid.NewGuid(); //This doesn't seem thread-safe, but I'm not certain given the AsyncLocal.
}

This feels like a good place to use a Lazy<T>, but I don't see a good way to slot it in here. Maybe I'm missing something obvious.

_asyncFlowId.Value should be thread safe, according to docs: "AsyncLocal instances can be used to persist data across threads". The changes from other thread shouldn't be seen, no need to sync.

Yep, different threads have different initial value, only child inherit value set by parent: test.

On .NET(Core) when you instantiate an AsyncLocal<T> - static/instance field or local variable - it creates an object on the heap whose reference would act as a key for the private dictionary-like object each separate ExecutionContext instance maintains. This object holds your AsyncLocal<T>.Value at dict[AsyncLocal]. Each thread (static Thread.CurrentThread) has an ExecutionContext which is used to get the values for the AsyncLocal<T>s.
One of the reasons you won't need locks is that ExecutionContext itself is immutable, so every time you set a value for an AsyncLocal<T> it will create a new ExecutionContext with the copied dictionary-like object and will set dict[AsyncLocal] to a new value.
For example, if you set the AsyncLocal.Value = X in the Main Thread and then fork into two other threads with default methods (Thread.Start/ThreadPool.QueuerWorkItem (not the UnsafeXXX ones) or the async/await infrastructure - the same ExecutionContext object will be flown/copied to the two other threads. But any change to an AsyncLocal<T> will involve creating a new context, so logically no race condition is possible.
